# apache shiro - session is lost when the server restarts?

Tags: spring, shiro

I'm using Apache Shiro Security. 
My settings ehcache.xml

```
    <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        />

<cache name="shiro-activeSessionCache"
       maxElementsInMemory="10000"
       overflowToDisk="true"
       eternal="true"
       timeToLiveSeconds="0"
       timeToIdleSeconds="0"
       diskPersistent="true"
       diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="600"/>
```

[EHCache Session Cache Configuration](http://shiro.apache.org/session-management.html#SessionManagement-EHCacheSessionDAO)

I use these settings on two different Tomcats. I do restart the server, the first sessions are saved, the second is not. What could it be?

Comment: well, one config has diskPersistent true and the other has false